# Can't get <select> input from form?

Tags: jquery, forms

I can figure out how to loop through input and select. My function below does not include select lists.

Any help welcome.

```
$('input', '#consumer_form').each(function(key, value)
{                   
    if ((this.type === "radio" || this.type === "checkbox") && this.checked === false) {
        return;
    } else {
         val = this.value;
    }

         //alert($('#'+this.id).attr('name')+'='+replaceAmp(val));
             formData += '&'+this.name+'='+replaceAmp(val); 

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Selects are `select` elements, not `input` elements.

Comment: would you mind posting your html :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's $(":input") you're need if you want to loop through all the elements in the form http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/    (you don't have a colon there).

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can get all `input` and select `elements` by doing this:

```
$('input, select')
```

So you would need to do something like

```
$('input, select').each(function(key, value) {                   
     if ($(this).is('select')) do_select_stuff();               
     else if ($(this).is(':checkbox')) do_checkbox_stuff();
     else if ($(this).is(':radio')) do_radio_stuff();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('input, select', '#consumer_form').each(function(key, value)
```